Stable points in GIT: geometric picture
Is there a geometric picture justifying why "stable points" in GIT (Geometric Invariant Theory) are actually called "stable"? Stable, with respect to which effect? (Here, I have the picture from "Stable Homotopy Theory" in mind, where intuitively the elements of stable homotopy groups $\pi_{k}^{S}:= \lim_n \pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ — often also called stable elements — bear this name from obvious reasons as these may be regarded to be "stable" under successive application of Hurewicz map.)
In GIT setting if $G/k$ acts on scheme $X/k$ then a point $x \in X(\bar{k})$ is called stable if its orbit under $G$ is closed, and its stabilizer is finite. By Hilbert–Mumford criterion this is equivalent to if and only if every $1$-parameter subgroup $\Bbb G_m \to G$ has positive (and negative) weights with
respect to $x$.
But this terminology seemingly doesn't really unveil immediately in which natural sense such
points are considered to be actually "stable". Is there a picture one
should keep in mind motivating this terminology?

I don't really have a good intuitive picture of the finite-stabiliser part, but I've always thought that closure of the orbit has a reasonable claim to being viewed as some sort of stability by itself.  For example, for the adjoint action of a reductive group on its Lie algebra, a non-$0$ nilpotent element $X$ is unstable, because you can approach $0$ along the orbit of $X$.

A point $x$ of a moduli space $\mathcal X$ is unstable if there is a map from $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathcal X$ that restricted to $\mathbb G_m$ is the composition of the constant map $\mathbb G_m \to \textrm{pt}$ with the map $\textrm{pt} \to X$ sending $x$ to $X$, but restricted to $0$ has image a different point $y$.
If this happens, you can be at point $x$, standing perfectly still, and suddenly find yourself at a diferent point $y$, which fits an intuitive quasi-physical notion of unstability.
If $\mathcal X$ is a quotient $X/G$, then this happens if there is a map $\mathbb A^1 \to X$ whose restriction to $\mathbb G_m$ is the translation of $x$ by the action of $G$ and a map $\mathbb G_m \to G$ and whose restriction to $0$ is not in the orbit of $x$, in other words (by the general theory) exactly when the orbit of $x$ is not closed.

Doesn't this motivate only semi-stability, not the stronger notion of stability?

@LSpice The notions themselves can be motivated in different ways - here the goal is only to explain why "stable" is an appropriate name. Since the two concepts are clearly related to each other, explaining why one is related to an intuitive notion of stability explains why both are related to an intuitive notion of stability.

That is a good way to remember the name, but it is ahistorical.  If you read "Geometric Invariant Theory", the original definitions of "stable," "properly stable," "strictly semistable," etc., are different from the definitions that are used today.  Based on the introduction to the book, I believe Mumford's motivation was to develop a notion that was consistent with earlier usage but more general, e.g., the moduli spaces $M_g$ had been constructed as quasi-projective schemes over arbitrary fields, but not over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

This is a non sequitur, but it is relevant to any discussion of the book.  There is a small mistake in Mumford's book in the proof of the main theorem.  When I guide students through the book, I encourage them to skip the proof there and read it in Dolgachev's book instead (Dolgachev organizes the proof in a way that avoids the mistake).

In case anybody wants a link to the mistake (and a further link to the Stacks Project Blog where Johan de Jong discusses what kind of quotients are intended by the theory), here is a MO link that discusses this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/440178

Thank you for sharing this picture!That's also a nice coincidence, I watched recently your video lecture on Number theory over function flds and I got a question about how you motivate the error term $O_{\epsilon}(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ in the count of primes in Dirichlet's arithmetic progression by means of probabilistic methods. If I not misunderstood you there you

refered briefly to central limit theorem. I posed recently a question about this point, could you maybe on occasion comment which CLT form you invoked
there treating numbers as random vars? motivating this asymptotic term?
The 'classical' CLT form seemingly not applies there as these rv's are
not identically distributed.

@JackYo The "Lyapunov CLT" applies to random variables that are independent but not identically distributed.

But still, we apply Lyapunov CLT to $X_1,..., X_n, n \le x$ with
RV $X_j$ taking value $1$ with probab $\frac{1}{\log j}$, and $0$ else, then
expected value $\mu_j =1/\log j$ and and variance $\sigma_j^2=
\frac{1}{\log j}-(\frac{1}{\log j})^2$.
Set $s^2_x:= \sum_{j \le x} \sigma_j^2$. If we fulfil the condition of Lyapunov CLT for appropr $\delta$ then
we would get $\frac{1}{s_x}(\sum_{j \le x} X_j- \mu_j)
\approx \frac{1}{s_x}(\sum_{j \le x} X_j - \int_2^x \frac{dy}{\log y})
\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

To get the approximation from your lecture
we would actually need $s^2_x \approx x^{1/2+\epsilon}$ +
a 'normalization' of the expected value sum/integral. Why does this actually hold?

@JackYo We need $s_x \approx x^{1/2+\epsilon}$ and therefore $s_x^2 \approx x^{1+\epsilon}$ which follows immediately from $s_x^2=\sum_{j\leq x} \sigma_j^2$ since $\sigma_j^2 \approx x^\epsilon$.

ah yes, one square to much! and then we get what we want almost surely
by $\Bbb P(\frac{1}{x^{1/2+\epsilon}}(\sum_{j \le x} X_j - \int_2^x \frac{dy}{\log y})<M)
\approx P(\frac{1}{s_x}(\sum_{j \le x} X_j- \mu_j)<M) \approx \Phi_{0,1}(M) \approx 1$ for big enough constant $M$ say $3 < M$. Thanks!

The Kempf-Ness theorem point of view on GIT roughly says that there is a function (the norm of a vector in a representation in their paper but there are other functions that work in different examples) whose
absolute minima are representatives of the "stable" orbits. The Kempf-Ness theorem characterizes the stable points as those for which the function achieves its infimum on the orbit of the point.  In this picture, if do a small enough perturbation of a stable point you always get a stable point (but not necessarily in the same orbit) because a small perturbation of a point near a minimum will flow back to a minimum.  A small perturbation near a non-minimal critical point can end up flowing down to a minimum. The Hilbert-Mumford criterion says you don't need to test stability by acting by the whole group, one parameter subgroups will do.   While I don't think that the "Morse theory"-like picture is the original motivation for the terminology (but the openness probably is), at least the Morse theory picture is evocative and makes the terminology quite sensible.

I am posting an answer that expands my comment.  The posted question could mean, "What is the essential aspect of 'stable points' to a mathematician today?"  However, it could also mean, "Why did Mumford use 'stable points' for this notion in the early 1960s?"  The second question is a matter of mathematical history.  Happily, Mumford has posted his early manuscripts about "Geometric Invariant Theory" on his webpage, even his unpublished manuscripts (and English translations of articles published in other languages).  Here is the URL.
https://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/moduli.html
In my reading of these manuscripts, there seem to be two essential points.  First, "stability" is related to the "stabilizer group" of an orbit, namely finiteness of the stabilizer group.  Mumford's original definition in the textbook does not require finiteness of stabilizer groups, but rather equidimensionality of stabilizer groups.  Perhaps this is so that the stable locus is unchanged when we replace an action of a group scheme $G$ on $X$ by an action of a bigger group scheme $G\times H$ on $X$, where $H$ acts trivially.
Second, Mumford repeatedly emphasizes that the key is the whole sequence of natural rational transformations that are equivariant for the action of $G$.  What is the common regular locus of all of these rational transformations?  Mumford identifies an open subscheme, the "stable locus," where the "natural" $G$-equivariant rational transformations are regular.  Thus, "stable" can also mean "stable" under the system of "natural" $G$-equivariant rational transformations.
What are the "natural" $G$-equivariant rational transformations?  These are the ones than can be expressed via projective geometry starting from the given $G$-equivariant projective embedding $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^N$.  This gives that the stable locus should be an open subscheme of the maximal open subscheme on which at least one $G$-invariant section of at least one positive tensor power of the $G$-linearized invertible $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(1)|_X$ is nonzero, i.e., the open subscheme that Mumford calls the "semistable locus."
Taken together, this explains Mumford's notation: the stable locus should be an open subscheme of the maximal open subscheme (the "semistable locus") where all "natural" $G$-equivariant rational transformations are regular morphisms.  Also, when restricted over the stable locus, the "stabilizer group scheme" should be flat (that is Mumford's original definition, although the algebraic geometry community later replaced "flat" by "quasi-finite and flat").  The maximal open subscheme satisfying both of these conditions is Mumford's definition of the "stable locus."
Why do I believe this?  I have not asked Mumford whether this is the reason he called this open subscheme the "stable locus."  However, it jibes with another fact about "Geometric Invariant Theory": even though Mumford began the project (at the urging of Zariski) as a way to construct the coarse moduli space $M_{g,\mathbb{Z}}$ as a quasi-projective scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, and even though Mumford constructs $M_{g,\mathbb{Z}}$ as a quasi-projective scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ in his textbook, he does not actually use any GIT analysis to do this.  Nor could he: the main theorems of "Geometric Invariant Theory" were originally proved only for schemes of finite type over a characteristic zero field.  This was extended to positive characteristic (largely through the work of William Haboush) and then to mixed characteristic (by Seshadri), but that was much later.  Originally, Mumford used an explicit sequence of $G$-equivariant rational transformations.  In fact, Mumford's first published article proving quasi-projectivity of $M_{g,\mathbb{Z}}$ never used any notion of "stable points," "semistable points," or anything similar.  He simply wrote down the requisite $G$-equivariant rational transformations and deduced quasi-projectivity of $M_{g,\mathbb{Z}}$ from these.

For anyone else wondering, as I did, about your reference to a comment that doesn't seem to appear on the original question, I think you mean the one on @WillSawin's answer.

I love these thoughtful geometric insights.  On the historical side, it may interest to read what Mumford said in 2021:
https://bhavana.org.in/beyond-the-three-bridges-around-the-world/
“What really started things off was the moduli space of n points on a projective line. Suppose you take the collection of n points, and you want to divide them out by projective equivalence, i.e. PGL(2,−) acting on the projective line. It’s perfectly clear that passing to a limit, one does not have a Hausdorff topology. The question was, can one find a big subset which behaves well?
And indeed, there was all this stuff in Clebsch and Gordan on explicit invariants. As it turned out, I stumbled on the fact that if there is no point whose multiplicity is greater than or equal to n/2, then you do indeed have a Hausdorff moduli space, when you divide by group equivalence. The word stable came from thinking of these
n points on a seesaw, and if more than half of them all go to one side, the seesaw was going to tip down in that direction, and it was therefore unstable. So, that was where the silly word came from. “
